# How to build Android application with Ant?

Tags: android, ant

I have an android project, which uses latest Google API's and Android 15 SDK to build. It also has additional libraries - *.so, *.jar, and assets and resources, if the last two makes any difference. 
So I would like to build this project via Ant, so I can use that script in my further CruiseControl configuration.

Currently I have only `build.xml` which automatically generated via this command:

```
android update project --path .
```

What should I change to include, those libraries and resources if needed. Please write down the simplest example with library usage.
Thank you on advance.

Comment: Have you tried building from the generated `build.xml`?

Comment: yes, I tried, but agter building apk is much more smaller, than usual on 5 mb

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3217643/324625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your JARs in `libs/`. Set up your Android library projects via the instructions found in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html), mostly involving modifying `project.properties`. You were already building the NDK pieces via the command line using `ndk-build`.

Comment: sorry for such a dummy question but in to a libs/ folder of which directory android-sdks ?

Comment: @unresolved_external: Create the `libs/` directory in the root of your project, if it is not already there.

Comment: @unresolved_external: Fantastic! So, you should be set. If you have problems with your setup, open up a new StackOverflow question with **specific, precise symptoms** of those problems, so you can get better help than rather than demanding that we "write down the simplest example with library usage".

Comment: I hope this is not a sarcasm)

Comment: @unresolved_external: No, it's a statement that we cannot help you much, since you felt that it was unnecessary to tell us what actually was wrong. Hence, if you have problems with your setup, open up a new StackOverflow question with specific, precise symptoms of those problems.